# dotless fails to build CSS randomly

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, less, dotless

I am having trouble tracking the source of why dotless is failing to build stylesheets. We have 8 load balanced servers.

At certain times, a user will hit the site and the stylesheets will not compile, producing a blank page. I have not been able to get any information from error logs as to what failed. Once they fail to compile, they will not work again, requiring a restart.

We are using query string parameters so that our urls look like:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/less/_init.less?pageId=5308&pageName=index">
```

This string is populating fine on the site. Dotless is used to capture those parameters so that our less looks like:

```
.settings() when (@pageId = 5308) and (@pageName = index) { html {color:red;} }
.settings;
```

The site will be fine, and then suddenly not work. In our development environment we never saw this fail. But once it was launched with heavier traffic it began to fail frequently.

Anyone seen anything like this? It's consistent across all of our servers so it's definitely an issue with the code not compiling.

I did two things to the `<dotless />` entry in my `web.config` that appears to have temporarily fixed this issue, but I think it is sub-optimal. I made `minifyCSS="true"` (which we had turned off for other reasons) and set `cache="false"`.

It's my belief that turning off caching in the `web.config` was helpful in preventing the above problem, but harmful for performance.

Comment: I've also encountered this issue, and have filed a bug report

https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/389